# How to add an image to my src when selected

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to display images in my src when a user selects a new image from my file input.
I'm starting off with setting my img src in my React app to `src={"http://localhost:3000/" + this.props.file}` which works fine, where `this.props.file` is something like `public/1583271311520-audioplayer.jpg` which I got from my data from my database in a fetch request

```
    this.state = {
          image: {},
        };

   componentDidMount() {
    const { match: { params} } = this.props;
        let album = this.state.album;
        fetch(`http://localhost:3000/albums/${params.albumId}`)
        .then((response) =>
          response.json())
        .then((data) => {
              this.setState({ image: data[0].path });

            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log("Error " + error)
              })
     }
```

Where data looks like this:

[image]

`this.props.file`s parent is this `file={this.state.image}`

My question is how can I add `event.target.files[0]` to my img src when a user selects it using the file input so that I can have an image displayed there when a new image is selected.

I'm setting the image at first to

`<img src={" http://localhost:3000/" + this.props.file} />`

While I'm trying to set onChange here:

`<input type="file" onChange={this.props.onChange} />`

```
onChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.files[0])
    this.setState({
      image: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]),
    });
  }
```

But I think my problem is that when setting my image onChange that the image I'm setting isn't from `localhost:3000` so it's not rendering correctly. So how can I add an image to my img src using onChange or something else when a user selects an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're saying is the image URL from when the user chooses a file (generated by `URL.createObjectURL()`) is not working, but that you've already identified the problem is that that URL is being appended onto the localhost domain, i.e. `<img src={" http://localhost:3000/" + this.props.file} />`.

You're pretty close to answering your own question, then, since you've discovered the problem. Just store that host part of the URL as part of state:

```
.then((data) => {
    this.setState({ image: `http://localhost:3000/${data[0].path}` });
```

Now when you use the image from the AJAX call, it will have the full domain, but when you use the URL blob (from the uploaded file) it won't.